# SQLCMD error: Incorrect syntax near '-'

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am trying to connect to a local sql express Database using the following command:

```
sqlcmd -S SERVER2008OS-DB\SQLEXPRESS -U XXXXX-P XXXXX
```

I am getting the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '-'.

My guess is that it is because our server has a '-' sign in its name,
What will be the correct syntax to overcome this issue?

Thanks alot

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/219925/how-do-quotes-strings-work-in-powershell)

Comment: Have you tried putting the server name in double quotes? `sqlcmd -S "SERVER2008OS-DB\SQLEXPRESS" -U XXXXX-P XXXXX`

Comment: Hi, Im afraid its not a duplicate - the link you provided is referring to an issue with Powershell and is not addressing the issue I presented

Comment: Hi @marc_s, Yes Im afraid I already tried it but still the same error is showing

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the server name in single quotes, or square brackets?